# Handling PHP array of unknown size

Tags: php, html

I have the following code that should select all the users in the relevant table in my database:

```
$hof = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

$name = array();
$website = array();
$i=0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($hof)){
$name[$i] = $result['company']; 
$website[$i] = $result['website'];
}
$i++;
```

I want to echo out the names and websites of all in the html section of my script (below the php) which will be a Hall of Frame of sorts.  How would i do is?  The fact that i do not know the size of the array deters me.

Usually, if i knew the size, i would so something like:

```
<?php echo $name[1];?>
<?php echo $name[2];?>
//and so on
```

Many thanks in advance.  P.S. I plan to move across to MySQLi when i have the functionality of the website sorted first on localhost.  Cheers

Comment: why you putting $i++; is outside of while loop???

Comment: yeah, sorry, copied it over wrong

Comment: **1)** Use of the `mysql_*` family is discuoraged. In fact, the whole set of functions [has been deprecated for quite a long time now](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). **2)**  Read about [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) **3)** Read about [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) **4)** Read about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$i++;` statement should be inside while loop

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($hof)){
    $name[$i] = $result['company']; 
    $website[$i] = $result['website'];
    $i++;
}
```

**Better** You do it like this,

```
$rows = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($hof)){
        $rows[] = $result; 
}
```

and you echo them like this,

```
<?php
$len = count($name);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    echo $name[1];
}
?>
```

And for the alternative method use this,

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row['name']; // use $row['website'] to echo website.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would i order the output?  So that it is not without spaces and ordered horizontally?

Comment: @Hector to order it you should order it in sql. use `ORDER BY` clause in sql. If you want to keep it horizontal do it in html

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($name as $key=>$value){
  echo $name[$key];
  echo $website[$key];
}
```

Also there no need to take `$i++`, you can use following way

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($hof)){
  $name[] = $result['company']; 
  $website[] = $result['website'];
}
```

See [array in manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Can you use CSS design in relation to php output?  So i can change the font color, or whatever of the php...That was why i had wanted it in html.  Thanks nevertheless

Comment: You should show your html where you want to use ? does your php contains html ? or it's separate .html file ?

Comment: Sorry i realised that was a dumb question.  Of course i can put the php echo script in the html.

Answer (score 3):

First off the `$i++` should be *inside* the loop.

To output them all, you could use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), or maybe [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

Answer (score 1):

First, take your data into array

```
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."[$sql]");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $data[] = $row; 
}
```

then use it anywhere you wish, say, in the template:

```
<ul>
<? foreach($data as $row): ?>
    <li><a href="<?=$row['website']?>"><?=$row['company']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach ($name as $val)
{
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql_num_rows() to know the number of results returned by your query

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrarySize = mysql_num_rows($hof);
```